# Ubuntu wont install since windows 10 reformat

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, windows-10, usb-installation

I tried Ubuntu once on a windows 7 PC. Switched back to windows because of gaming. Now I want to install it on exactly the same machine (besides ram upgrade and windows 10 upgrade) because of Uni.
But... It just doesn't work that easy anymore.

I put up a USB stick as explained on the Ubuntu website using ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64 as recommended with rufus-2.14.
Just doesn't work. It just freezes on boot:
[image: Boot screenshot]

Then I found my old installation disc of Ubuntu 14.04.3 that worked once and obviously should still do the same thing. But when I boot this one it shows me "Booting from CD" two times and then windows just starts...

My machine has AMD Phemton II X4 945 Processor, x64, 16 GB RAM, Mainboard: Gigabyte Technology: GA-MA785GMT-UD2H

**UPDATE:**
I found out some additional things: My BIOS doesnt have UEFI, it runs in Legacy mode. 
Secure Boot state is unsupported.

Upcoming questions of mine: Is it even possible in this BIOS to install a dual-boot system just like that?
Or should I maybe completely reformat my system or partition my hard-drive for it to work?

Best,
Till

Comment: Don't confuse Secure Boot and FastBoot.

Comment: BIOS doesn't have that options, UEFI does. Your screenshot is unlikely to be from a UEFI enabled machine.

Comment: @user535733 Yes what I meant is secureboot. Thanks.

Comment: @CelticWarrior And how to I install ubuntu from a no UEFI device?

Comment: If it worked before it should work again. My suspicion is that you've changed a BIOS option at some point and this is preventing the Ubuntu installer from booting. There's also a chance that a change to the disk partitions is causing the boot to fail.

Comment: @RodSmith i checked if there is any option helping in bios and there is none. 
So would you recommend try to do a partition in windows or reformat right away?

Answer (score 1):

If you already installed windows 10 in uefi mode, the ubuntu installation you're used to will fail.

You should first disable the FastBoot in windows before you can install ubuntu [Here's a link on how  to do it.](https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html)
Then, boot with your drive in EFI mode ( basically , [You must have something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/194UW.png)).

Sometimes,you may have a secure boot or signature error. Only then you must disable the secure boot.

Comment: Not likely to be UEFI looking at  that screenshot. OP is probably confused.

Comment: Hey im sorry, I turned off Fastboot but its still the same.
The only noticable difference is that when I boot from CD-ROM it wont boot to windows and just does nothing,

Comment: Try to open you boot menu (press F12) on startup and select your bootable device.

Comment: thats exactly what i did